# Could tm be able key concepts?

Tags: r, tm

I am dealing with text mining in R, with `tm` library. I know how to extract keywords but I would like to extract association of words that are frequently "together" in the document (for example get the expression `proof of concept` or `hydraulic jack`).

I know there is `findAssocs`function, but it seems to be only relevant if you want to know words correlated to a specific word... I would like to detect automatically "couples of words linked together".

Is it a way to do this with `tm` library ? Or in any other way on R ?

Thanks in advance

EDIT : using  `Quanteda`package, and especially, `fcm`function, I get an error (see [image] ). The function says it needs a dataframe but `DF`is already one...)

Answer (score 3):

The term you are looking for is co-occurence.

I know of two packages that could help you with this.

- Package `quanteda`: `fcm` function creates a sparse feature co-occurrence matrix
- Package `udpipe`: `cooccurence` function creates a cooccurence data.frame that indicates how many times each term co-occurs with another term.

Depending on your needs go for one or the other.

#### edit based on op's edit

Your DF is not a `dfm` object. It looks like a data.frame. `tidytext` has a function to transform a data.frame into a `dfm` for use in `quanteda`.

```
library(quanteda)
DF <- data.frame(term = c("anthony", "choonheyt", "construction", "direction"),
                 document = c(1,1,2,2),
                 count = c(1,1,1,1), stringsAsFactors = FALSE)


# cast as dfm from tidytext
x <- tidytext::cast_dfm(DF, document, term, count)
x
Document-feature matrix of: 2 documents, 4 features (50% sparse).
2 x 4 sparse Matrix of class "dfm"
    features
docs anthony choonheyt construction direction
   1       1         1            0         0
   2       0         0            1         1

fcm(x, context = "document", count = "frequency")

Feature co-occurrence matrix of: 4 by 4 features.
4 x 4 sparse Matrix of class "fcm"
              features
features       anthony choonheyt construction direction
  anthony            0         1            0         0
  choonheyt          0         0            0         0
  construction       0         0            0         1
  direction          0         0            0         0
```

Comment: Thank you for your relevant answer but can you have a look to my edit because I have a problem with quanteda package which looks fine for my needs however

Comment: Actually, I tried to use `window` context like this : `temp <-fcm(corp, context="window",frequency="count",window=3)` where `corp` is a simple corpus but it says to me that `fcm` can only apply on corpus object. Is there a way to convert a simpleCorpus to a Corpus ? I am actually a bit surprised that SimpleCorpus is not considered as a Corpus...

Comment: Do you have any idea about that ?

Comment: @MysteryGuy, `temp <-fcm(corpus(corp), context="window",frequency="count",window=3)` will do the trick. It will transform the `tm` simple corpus` into a corpus that `quanteda` can use.

Answer (score 1):

For the udpipe R package. There is a vignette which handles exactly that question: https://cran.r-project.org/web/packages/udpipe/vignettes/udpipe-usecase-postagging-lemmatisation.html